# Use purrr::map*() to assign a nested list element to another nested list

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse, purrr

I have two lists:

```
listA <- list(group1 = tibble(names = LETTERS[1:5],
                              names_num = 1:5),
              group2 = tibble(names = LETTERS[11:13],
                              names_num = 1:3))
  
listB <- list(group1 = list(labels = NULL,
                            order = 5:1),
              group2 = list(labels = NULL,
                            order = 3:1))
```

My goal is to modify `listB$groupX$labels` by inserting the `names` vector from `listA` for each group, and in the order specified by `listB$groupX$order`. The desired output would look like this:

```
> listB_mod
$group1
$group1$labels
[1] "E" "D" "C" "B" "A"
$group1$order
[1] 5 4 3 2 1

$group2
$group2$labels
[1] "M" "L" "K"
$group2$order
[1] 3 2 1
```

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably using the purrr::map() family?

Any hints much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the logic is unrelated to ‘purrr’ functionality but of course you can use `map2` to apply the logic to all pairwise items in the two lists:

```
listB_mod = map2(
    listA, listB,
    ~ list(labels = .x$names[match(.x$names_num, .y$order)], order = .y$order)
)
```

Comment: great, thanks! And if I was to create `listB_mod` through `listB_mod <- listB %>% map2(listA, ~ ....)`, what would I have to adjust?

Comment: Since you’re swapping the `listA` and `listB` arguments, you’d need to swap `.x` and `.y` inside the call.

Comment: yes, that worked. Also, if I wanted to leave other list elements unchanged, `~ purrr::list_modify(.x, labels = ....)` did the trick.